# Есть ли разница в использовании PermissionChecker и ContextCompat для проверки permissions?

Tags: android, permissions

В 23 api добавили класс - PermissionChecker.

Судя по документации этот класс отвечает только за проверку permissions.
Есть ли разница как проверять разрешения для приложения,
так:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
```

или так:

```
PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В 23 api добавили не класс, а [изменили принципы работы с разрешениями](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Если раньше разрешения просто прописывались в манифест и запрашивались при установке приложения, то теперь [часть разрешений](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous) необходимо запрашивать исключительно в рантайме. Собственно этот класс является составной частью этого механизма.

В общем случае, как и [написано в документации](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), необходимо использовать `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission`.

> To check if you have a permission, call the ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() method.

О `PermissionChecker` информации достаточно мало, но то, что есть, позволяет сделать вывод, что данный метод необходим в достаточно редких случаях, когда ваше приложение должно взаимодействовать со сторонними, старыми, приложениями, в которых не реализован механизм запроса разрешений в рантайме, так как пользователь может в `compatibility mode` отозвать разрешения у этих приложений.

То есть, фактически, проверяется не только наличие разрешения, но и что оно разрешено. простите за тавтологию.

> It is important that when you perform an operation on behalf of another app you use these APIs to check for permissions as the app may be a legacy app that does not participate in the new permission model for which the user had disabled the "permission" which is achieved by disallowing the corresponding app op.

Comment: Если я верно понимаю, то можно получать данные о тех или иных пермишенов и без PermissionChecker. Все таки есть задачи которые без PermissionChecker не обойтись?

Comment: @abbath0767 получать - да. Но не забывайте, что если вы принудительно, в коде, не запросите эти разрешения, то их не будет и проверку можно смело считать провалившейся

Comment: @abbath0767 дополнил ответ

Comment: благодарю за развернутый ответ!